# Prevent Json.NET from deserializing arrays of strings as arrays of key-value pairs

Tags: c#, json, json.net

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` successfully deserializes `['a','b']` as `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. I would like it to fail, only succeeding when the input string is like `[{'Key':'a','Value':'b'}]`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, you would have to read out the string and test with a regular expression if it has the desired format.

Comment: @xsquared can you post a regex that validates any  json?

Comment: I wonder if this is intrinsic ('hard coded') or though a standard converter..

Comment: @user2864740 How about posting a real comment instead of making fun of my english

Comment: @user2864740 OK, what did you mean then?

Comment: @Eser It was a pedantic play on words that I removed because it was pointless; both readings of 'any' are correct.

Comment: Apologies for my regEx suggestion, I didn't really pay attention yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you may have found a bug in Json.NET's [`KeyValuePairConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/KeyValuePairConverter.cs), namely that it assumes the reader is positioned at the beginning of a JSON object rather than checking and validating that it is.  You could [report an issue on it](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) if you want.

In the meantime, the following [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) will correctly throw a [`JsonException`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm) for your case:

```
public class KeyValueConverter : JsonConverter
{
    interface IToKeyValuePair
    {
        object ToKeyValuePair();
    }

    struct Pair<TKey, TValue> : IToKeyValuePair
    {
        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

        public object ToKeyValuePair()
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(Key, Value);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);

        return type.IsGenericType
            && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } } // Use Json.NET's writer.

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);

        if (isNullable && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        if (type.IsGenericType
            && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
        {
            var pairType = typeof(Pair<,>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments());
            var pair = serializer.Deserialize(reader, pairType);
            if (pair == null)
                return null;
            return ((IToKeyValuePair)pair).ToKeyValuePair();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Invalid type: " + objectType);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
        string json = @"['a','b']";

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new KeyValueConverter() } };
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(json, settings);
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zpgUc3).

**Update**

To force an error when the JSON contains a non-existent property, use [`JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm).

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
            Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new KeyValueConverter() },
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it fail as expected for "['a','b']".  However, it still succeeds for the following, which seem like they should also fail: [{'a':'b','c':'d'}]" (because its fields aren't named Key and Value) and "[{'Key':{'x':1},'Value':false}]" (because the key isn't a string).
Do you have any idea how to fix that in a generic way (without hard-coding the converter to <sring, object>?